# How to post to Monday API using Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm using Axios to post data to Monday API from a react app.

You'll find the dev page on Monday here:
https://developers.monday.com/#!/boards/POST_version_boards_board_id_pulses_format

Here is my code:

```js
function postForm() {
  axios.post('https://api.monday.com:443/v1/boards/MY_BOARD/pulses.json?api_key=MY_API_KEY', {
      name: "Jonathan"
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I get status code 400 on this code. How to config the axios post method correct?

Comment: Did you replace MY_BOARD and MY_API_KEY in the url?

Comment: @user2177591 yes I did.

Comment: Use you can try to use this library : mondayapi. It allows you to not use axios and get typed response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the doc 3 parameters are flagged as required.

-board_id which you provide in the url

-user_id which you should provide in the request's body

-pulse[name] which you should also provide in the request's body

You are getting a http 400 because you're not providing those requested params (user_id and pulse[name]).

pulse[name] is the name of the new pulse you are trying to create and user_id should be an integer (you'll have to figure Jonathan's id if you want him to be the pulse's owner)

it should look like this :

```
function postForm() {
  axios.post('https://api.monday.com:443/v1/boards/MY_BOARD/pulses.json?api_key=MY_API_KEY', {
  user_id: 0, 
  pulse: {
      name: "Jonathan's pulse"
  }
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

}

Comment: Oh, that's was the problem! Thanks!